# How to change permissions of a file to only be read by my program

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web

I'm in the middle of creating an ASP.net website, and I'm starting to wonder what is the best way to store my connection string.

After [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900957/is-it-safe-to-write-connection-string-in-web-config), a user recommends that you store the connection string in a text file, and change the permissions to only be used by your application.

I currently have it stored in web.config, so would it be fine to set the web.configs permissions instead? I do plan on encrypting it as well.

Can someone give me a push in the right direction for how to do this?

If you are going to down vote my question, please give me a reason why.

Comment: storing it in the config file is fine. If you want you can encrypt it as well. That should be enough. Depends on the application.

Comment: The web.config allows you to encrypt the connection string so that it's only decryptable by the application at run-time. Using an external file prevents you from this benefit as well as having to manually load it/parse it.

Comment: To be fair, it's virtually impossible to encrypt web.config in such a way that *nobody* other than the application can decrypt it - ultimately the Administrator user will have the ability to give themselves the permission to decrypt it for themselves. But at least then there'd be an audit trail of them having done so.  You could do the same with any file, but the built-in support for encrypted web.config files does make it easier.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did not know that. When you search similar topics you get so many contradictions, this is the first thing that has made complete sense to me.